# How to convert TIMESTAMP to SECONDs in H2?

Tags: sql, h2

I have a table

```
   CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE (id int, my_date timestamp);
```

and data:

```
   INSERT INTO MY_TABLE (id, my_date) VALUES (1, '2015-08-04 05:41:02')
```

How to select `my_date` in `seconds`: 2015-08-04 05:41:02  ---- >  1438656062 in `H2 database`

Comment: The result should be 1438666862, not 1438656062. Reason: it's 16651 days, each one 86400 seconds, plus 20462 seconds within that day. You got 3 hours less, probably due to daylight saving changes.

Answer (score 3):

To convert a timestamp to millis, you could use

```
datediff('ms', '1970-01-01', now());
```

If you want it for seconds, try dividing it by 1000.

[Source](http://goobbe.com/questions/7850043/h2-database-now-as-nano-seconds)

Comment: For seconds, use `'s'` instead of `'ms'`.

Comment: Source is broken now

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest the following query:

```
SELECT
  *,
  CAST(DATEDIFF('SECOND','1970-01-01',MY_DATE) AS BIGINT) AS UNIX_TIMESTAMP
FROM MY_TABLE ;
```

Note that the cast as bigint may not be needed...

This works too:

```
SELECT
  *,
  DATEDIFF('SECOND','1970-01-01',MY_DATE) AS UNIX_TIMESTAMP
FROM MY_TABLE ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
SELECT parsedatetime(my_date, 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss') FROM my_tabe
```

Comment: UNIX_TIMESTAMP not found for H2?